# Count and sum the array lengths of child arrays nested in documents - MongoDB / PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have MongoDB documents like this:

```
{
    "_id": "object1",
    "type": "this_type",
    "child_array": [
        {...other fields here...},
        {...other fields here...},
        {...other fields here...}
    ],
    "some_other_key": "some_value"
},
{
    "_id": "object2",
    "type": "this_type",
    "child_array": [
        {...other fields here...},
        {...other fields here...}
    ],
    "some_other_key": "some_value"
},
{
    "_id": "object3",
    "type": "this_type",
    "child_array": [
        {...other fields here...},
        {...other fields here...},
        {...other fields here...},
        {...other fields here...}
    ],
    "some_other_key": "some_value"
}
```

Is it possible to count how many nested children the `child_array`s have?

I am currently using this, but it returns `3`, because 3 documents have the `child_array`.

```
$collection = $mongodb->my_collection;
$nested_count_filter = [ "type" => "this_type", "child_array" => ['$exists' => true] ];
$nested_count = $collection->count($nested_count_filter);
```

I need it to return `9` for this example, as the first doc has 3, the second has 2, and the 3rd has 4, totaling 9 nested children.

Is there a MongoDB way to do this, or do I have to do this manually (eg, for loops)?

#### UPDATE - Solution

I tried:

```
$mongo_count = $collection.aggregate([
  [ '$match' => [ 'type' => 'this_type' ] ],
  [ '$group' => [
    '_id' => null,
    'child_array' => [ '$sum' => [ '$size'=> '$child_array' ]]
  ]]
]);
```

To get the actual counts, after using the method in the accepted answer, the Mongo cursor object has to be converted to an array:

```
$count_array = iterator_to_array($mongo_count);
$count = $count_array[0]['child_array'];
```

Comment: you can use `$size` aggregation operator to count number of elements inside the `child_array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with `null` and [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the `child_array` array

```
$collection.aggregate([
  [ '$match' => [ 'type' => 'this_type' ] ],
  [ '$group' => [
    '_id' => null,
    'child_array' => [ '$sum' => [ '$size'=> '$child_array' ]]
  ]]
])
```

which is similar to javascript

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "type": "this_type" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "child_array": { "$sum": { "$size": "$child_array" }}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Corrected some basic PHP syntax (ie, `$match`, `$group`, `$sum`, and `$size` have to be in single quotes, otherwise it thinks they are PHP variables).  Also, should `'$size"'=> "$child_array"` be `'$size"'=> "child_array"`?  But then when I try it, I get this error `The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: String`.  If I try it by magically(?) using the nested-child object name as a variable (eg, `'$size'=> '$child_array'`, where `child_array` is just the name of a child array in a Mongo JSON document), I get an empty cursor.

Comment: thanks for the correction... You have to use dollar `$` sign here `'$size'=> '$child_array'` which shows the field is from document not a string

Comment: Tried it exactly, as well as with some variations, but still just get an empty cursor.  Please see my update.

Comment: Might be your collection deos not have`type => "this_type"` ... ok run a simple query with `$collection.aggregate([])` or `$collection.find([])` and let me know what result you are getting with this...

Comment: Updated with the result of the unfiltered aggregate, as well as a sample result from traversing the cursor in a for loop.